# Como pegar um array de uma tabela e buscar em outra tabela em Ionic e AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic

Tenho um campo numa tabela com um `array` de números:

```
2;3;7;8;9;10;11;15;1
```

Cada número destes corresponde a um ID de uma outra tabela. Preciso listar os itens desta outra tabela de acordo com o array. Não estou conseguindo chegar a uma lógica favorável.

Alguma solução?

Comment: Não ficou muito claro para mim quando você diz "outra tabela". Esses dados estão em um array, array de objetos? Se sim, poderia usar o filter.

Comment: @Ramos esse array de números é separado com ; mesmo?

Comment: Alguma das resposta lhe foi útil? Não esqueça de escolher uma e marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz um [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/6vcYtFHBG4VKccAGKDbA) para tentar exemplificar. Veja se é isso que você precisa.

Comment: Olá Danilo, acho que o que ele quer é o contrário, ele quer pegar tudo referente ao primeiro array

Comment: Opa, boa tarde. Nesse caso ele pode alterar a condição.

Comment: @DaniloSilva Seu exemplo foi perfeito. Mas olha no Plunk que fiz a respeito do que estou tentando fazer. Tem alguma coisa muito errada no meu código: https://plnkr.co/edit/Ovg4WHLTdNeOM9Eeae8c?p=preview

Comment: @DaniloSilva Tentei também:  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.array2.length; i++){
                   if ( $scope.array1.indexOf(parseInt($scope.array2[i].categoria_comida_cod_categoria_com)) >= 0 ){
                      
                    $scope.array3.push($scope.array2[i]);
                       
                     }
                    
                 }

Comment: Mas mesmo resultado.

Comment: @Ramos, Haviam algumas inconsistência no seu código. Veja o código [link]http://plnkr.co/edit/2q1dYUsIscHXiv6dbBMR?p=preview com a correção. Agora é só fazer a lógica conforme a sua necessidade.

Comment: Pessoal, muito obrigado! :))))